# WCF Service : Improve Database Connection Initialization

Tags: wcf, stateless

My wcf service operation contract runs a code to initialize the database connection to fetch data. Database initialization does take some time resulting in low performance . Is there something i can do with my WCF service to overcome this situation. With my desktop application, the connection was required to be set only once and hence it was not much of a problem.

ServiceBehaviour is currently set as instanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall and ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple

Should I be using a persession context mode or any stateful behaviour. No ideas if there is something i can work upon instead of relying on database team to rectify the initialization problems ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pool of connections to avoid the handshake and new connection on each request.
Here, some document about SQL-Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

You could also use a singleton behavior or even a static connection, but these two last options are not the best choices.

Comment: hey thanks for sharing the ideas. Since i need to connect to a file system database developed within the company , there isn't many options available at the database side to resolve this case. However i am eager to know more on how i can achieve this with singleton and static connection . Also what are the disadvantages on doing this ?

Comment: as you said your database is a file system, I don't think you will have problems using a static connection. I imagine that this file system does not manage connections as database engine, like SQL Server or Oracle (connection pool, timeout, state, etc), so I think using a static connection can be a good approach, but it requires tests. Singleton implementation can be done within your service. Just must keep in mind that you will have only one instance for all calls, this can cause performance issues, so use carefully.